# call_user_func_array() passes array as string bug?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP 5.4.25. Take the following code:

```
<?php

function works($params=[])
{
    var_dump(is_array($params));
    var_dump($params);

    $params = (array) $params;

    var_dump(is_array($params));
    var_dump($params);

    $params['first_name'] = "Bob";
}

function fails($params=[])
{
    var_dump(is_array($params));
    var_dump($params);

    $params['first_name'] = "Bob";
}

call_user_func_array('works', ['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']);
call_user_func_array('fails', ['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']);
```

Results:

```
bool(false)

string(4) "John"

bool(true)

array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "John"
}

bool(false)

string(4) "John"

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in /vhosts/site/test.php on line 14
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vhosts/site/test.php:0
PHP   2. call_user_func_array() /vhosts/site/test.php:17
PHP   3. fails() /vhosts/site/test.php:17
```

It appears that the array passed is not a valid array... It shows only the first value of the array and as a string instead of an array... But you can then cast the string as an array and then it works fine.....

The solution is obviously to just cast it as an array at the beginning of the function, but it seems like you shouldn't have to do this. Is this a PHP bug? I can't seem to find any other reports of this.

Comment: To pass an actual array argument into `fails`: `call_user_func_array('fails', [['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']]);`

Comment: That is a weird trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, `call_user_func_array()` takes an array, and passes it into a function as individual arguments.

If you have a function `do_something($a, $b, $c)` you can do `call_user_func_array("do_something", array(1, 2, 3))` and it will call `do_something(1, 2, 3)`.  If you just need to call the function and pass the array as an argument, you can use `call_user_func`.

It sounds like you want to do:

```
call_user_func('works', ['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']);
```

If you insist on using `call_user_func_array`, I suppose you could do:

```
call_user_func_array('works', [['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']]);
```

Which is passing an array of arrays, so it will take the single element in the array and pass it as the argument to the function.

Another options, if the method is dynamic, is to simply do something like this:

```
$method = "works";
$method(['first_name'=>'John', 'last_name'=>'Doe']);
```

Comment: Interesting. How come I can cast the first argument as an array and get the whole passed array then?

Comment: You could json encode or serialize the array and pass it as that, then in your function json decode/unserialze it.

Answer (score 1):

Although the original question asked about PHP 5.4.25, in versions since PHP 5.6, the answer can be simplified with the triple dot variable-length argument lists feature.

```
call_user_func_array('foo', ['a', 'b', 'c']);

function foo(...$params) {
  // $params = ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list